# How to pass value from table in one feature file to another feature file's JSON request?

Tags: karate

In feature file 1:

```
Feature: validate the table
Scenario: Table parameterization

And table kit
| homeMobileCountryCode    | homeMobileNetworkCode |    radioType   |   carrier     |   considerIp  |   cellTowers  |   wifiAccessPoints    |
| 310                      | 410                   |    'GSM'       |   'Vodafone'  |   'true'      |               |                       |
| 200                      | 500                   |    'GSM'       |   'Vodafone'  |   'true'      |               |                       |
| 100                      | 350                   |    'GSM'       |   'Vodafone'  |   'true'      |               |                       |


And def result = call read( ' classpath:2.2_parameter_pass.feature ') kit
And print result
```

In feature file 2
    Feature: re-usable feature to create a single cat

```
Scenario:
And print "caled func"
Given url 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate' 
And param key = AIzaSyB2jt4BQ9McqBXAe8dYcp1CwKf0oGFlWuc
And request { homeMobileCountryCode : ' #(homeMobileCountryCode) ', homeMobileNetworkCode : ' #(homeMobileNetworkCode) ', radioType : ' #(radioType) ', carrier : ' #(carrier) ', considerIp : ' #(considerIp) ', cellTowers : ' #(cellTowers) ', wifiAccessPoints : ' #(wifiAccessPoints)'}
When method post
Then status 200
```

but the values are not passed successfully in JSON Request.

please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to figure out because you have not provided a complete working example nor have you given any idea of what error you are facing.

One thing that strikes me is this line is sure to fail, you should use quotes around the string

```
And param key = 'AIzaSyB2jt4BQ9McqBXAe8dYcp1CwKf0oGFlWuc'
```

You also have un-necessary spaces in the request e.g. `' #(radioType) '` which will cause trouble, make this `'#(radioType)'` and please be more careful.

Comment: Table values are not getting replaced on posting the request.In report we are able to see only this                                                                                                       
    {"homeMobileCountryCode":" #(homeMobileCountryCode)","homeMobileNetworkCode":"#(homeMobileNetworkCode)","radioType":"#(radioType)","carrier":"#(carrier)","considerIp":" #(considerIp)","cellTowers":"#(cellTowers)","wifiAccessPoints":"#(wifiAccessPoints)"}

Comment: @PreethiRavi I'm sorry this is a very poor description of your issue. how are you posting. what report. unless you provide more details, no one will be able to help you. at least I am giving up, maybe someone else can, all the best. also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm trying to utilise the "DataDriven Features" Functionality from Karate. https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features. The same example i tried with the GoogleMaps URI mentioned in the above question section. But, the value from Feature file 1 table was not passed to feature file 2. I have provided the Sure-fire Report-> Response message while running my feature file in the comment section. Thanks much for your clarification and reply.. Appreciate, if this explanation helps you

Comment: The above program is working fine now:     And def result = call read('classpath:table_petstore/table_post.feature') kittens